# Get alle coordinates within an area - Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I've made a website using the geolocation API, which shows if you're in Berlin or not. To get alle the coordinates I've selected Berlin in Google Maps and downloaded a KML file with these coordinates.

Now I would like to have all the coordinates within that selection, because in the KML file are only the coordinates of the border.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

*Get all the coordinates within an area* doesn't make sense because there are *literally* infinite coordinates within a polygon (depending on the resolution of your coordinates of course).

What you need is to check wheter a given point is contained within a polygon. You can do it using the `containsLocation()` method (see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation))